# Routing error: No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to build a meal tips calculator using form_tag and my form submissions generate a routing error. I spent an hour searching, but can't figure it out.

Error: No route matches [POST] "/tips"

My routes

```
Tips::Application.routes.draw do
  root "tips#calculate"
  get "tips/calculate"
  post "tips/calculate"
end
```

Controller:

```
class TipsController < ApplicationController
  def calculate
    @tip = params[:price].to_i * params[:tip].to_i
    render 'calculate'
  end
end
```

View:

```
<h1>Enter your meal info</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/tips/calculate.html.erb</p>
<%= form_tag('/tips#calculate') do %>
<p>
    <%= label_tag("Meal price:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:price, nil, placeholder: "Enter cost without tax and tip")%>
</p>
<p>
    <%= label_tag("Tip:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:tip, nil, placeholder: "Enter tip (i.e. 15 for 15%)") %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= submit_tag 'Calculate!' %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= label_tag("Tip value:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag("tip", @tip, precision: 2, :readonly => true) %> #this probably needs to be changed
<% end %>
```

Rake routes:

```
$ rake routes
        Prefix Verb URI Pattern               Controller#Action
          root GET  /                         tips#calculate
tips_calculate GET  /tips/calculate(.:format) tips#calculate
               POST /tips/calculate(.:format) tips#calculate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes file, you have declared an endpoint for POST requests at `/tips/calculate/`. In your form, however, you're trying to POST to `/tips#calculate`. The browser sees that `#calculate` as a fragment (aka a named anchor), and doesn't send that to the server.

Change your `form_tag` to read `form_tag('/tips/calculate')` and that error should go away.

Comment: The confusion probably stems from the different meanings of `#`. In the route listing, `tips#calculate` means "the `calculate` method in the `TipsController` class" whereas `#` in a URL is a fragment.

Comment: Yes, this fixes it! Cheers, too new, can't upvote. On a related note, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html says that `form_tag` should be able to be `<%= form_tag('form_calculate_path') do %>` but that also throws an error. Does anyone know of (better) form_tag examples/docs?

Comment: You should be able to use `form_tag(tips_calculate_path) ... `. You see the `prefix` column in the output of `rake routes`? You can append `_path` or `_url` to that name to get the path (from root ... usually /) or the url (as in, http://example.com/path/goes/here) respectively.